# MySQL replace .html links of given domain

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database there are contenfields with lots of internal links. I have to change link structure from www.mydomain.de/page.html to www.mydomain.de/page/, but replace statement should respect the domain:

This is whats expected to be replaced:

```
www.mydomain.de/somepage.html -> www.mydomain.de/page/
www.mydomain.de/subfolder/page.html -> www.mydomain.de/subfolder/page/
www.mydomain.de/link.html?param=1 -> www.mydomain.de/page/?param=1
www.mydomain.de/another-link.html#hash -> www.mydomain.de/page/#hash
```

All other links should be untouched, here some examples, but could be any link on the web:

```
 www.some-domain.de/link.html    
 www.another-domain.com/somelink.html
```

There can be different links in one contentfield:

```
<p>If you want to read more, click 
<a href="http://www.mydomain.de/page.html">here</a> 
or there <a href="http://www.another-domain.com/somelink.html">there</a>
```

This is doing the replace:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET contentfield = REPLACE(contentfield, '.html', '/')
```

My ideas (but don't know how to create a statement for them):

- WHERE within the previous 100 chars is found 'mydomain.de'
- WHERE number of ".html" found = number of "mydomain.de" found

It does not have to be 100% matching all 'mydomain.de' links, I am happy with 90%, but there should not be a wrong replacement in external links.

Comment: if this has to be done 100% in mysql / ansi sql, I think it can't be done ... unless of course, you now all the possible urls w/o query string (in which case it would be somewhat trivial). But if you don't ... The problem is, you can match the domain (and url) with a regular expression, but neither can you extract it into some interim variable/table/whatever nor can you replace with a regular expression. If you are willing to allow some external script to do the work, it would almost be trivial. if stored procedures are a possibility, there *might* be a solution, but it would probably be ugly.

Comment: How many times will appears  in `contentfield` for 'www.mydomain.de' at most? If unknown, this can not be done by just `update` statement.

Comment: @JPG well you could just run the update multiple times?

Comment: @Jakumi So a stored procedures could be a solution, isn't it?

Comment: actually, I have never written a stored procedure, I just assume it can be done. I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: @Andrea Would you consider using an external UDF library such as https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Have now made this into a blog post: http://stevettt.blogspot.co.uk/2018/02/a-mysql-regular-expression-replace.html

---

Please see the following Rextester Fiddle, which I think should produce all the results you have asked for:

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ULGYT84304)

**Explanation**

A pattern-replacing function is needed for this but unfortunately [MySQL doesn't provide such a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826). So I wrote one (based on another that wasn't quite sufficient) and have posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql/38660574#38660574). As mentioned in the referenced answer, this function has a limitation of not allowing substitution of capturing groups with backreferences. Hence it has been slightly adapted in the fiddle to take further parameters that allow it to perform a recursive replace in the found match for the replacement. (Note the use of allowed URL path characters in the regex as per [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669692#4669755)).

**Update SQL**

The following SQL will update the table data using the function below:

```
UPDATE urls
SET url = reg_replace(
  url,
  'www\\.mydomain\\.de/[-A-Za-z0-9\\._~!\\$&''\\(\\)\\*\\+,;=:@%/]+\\.html',
  '/[^/]+\\.html',
  '/page/',
  TRUE,
  22, -- Min match length = www.mydomain.de/?.html = 22
  0,  -- No max match length
  7,  -- Min sub-match length = /?.html = 7
  0   -- No max sub-match length
  );
```

**Function code**

The UDF code used in the demo is also posted below. Note: The UDF delegates to a stored procedure since [only stored procedures will allow recursion in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752078#3752641).

```
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- USAGE
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- SELECT reg_replace(<subject>,
--                    <pattern>,
--                    <subpattern>,
--                    <replacement>,
--                    <greedy>,
--                    <minMatchLen>,
--                    <maxMatchLen>,
--                    <minSubMatchLen>,
--                    <maxSubMatchLen>);
-- where:
-- <subject> is the string to look in for doing the replacements
-- <pattern> is the regular expression to match against
-- <subpattern> is a regular expression to match against within each
--              portion of text that matches <pattern>
-- <replacement> is the replacement string
-- <greedy> is TRUE for greedy matching or FALSE for non-greedy matching
-- <minMatchLen> specifies the minimum match length
-- <maxMatchLen> specifies the maximum match length
-- <minSubMatchLen> specifies the minimum match length
-- <maxSubMatchLen> specifies the maximum match length
-- (minMatchLen, maxMatchLen, minSubMatchLen and maxSubMatchLen are used to improve
--  efficiency but are optional and can be set to 0 or NULL if not known/required)
-- Example:
-- SELECT reg_replace(txt, '[A-Z0-9]{3}', '[0-9]', '_', TRUE, 3, 3, 1, 1) FROM tbl;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS reg_replace;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION reg_replace(subject VARCHAR(21845), pattern VARCHAR(21845),
  subpattern VARCHAR(21845), replacement VARCHAR(21845), greedy BOOLEAN,
  minMatchLen INT, maxMatchLen INT, minSubMatchLen INT, maxSubMatchLen INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(21845) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN
  DECLARE result VARCHAR(21845);
  CALL reg_replace_worker(
    subject, pattern, subpattern, replacement, greedy, minMatchLen, maxMatchLen,
    minSubMatchLen, maxSubMatchLen, result);
  RETURN result;
END;//
DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS reg_replace_worker;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE reg_replace_worker(subject VARCHAR(21845), pattern VARCHAR(21845),
  subpattern VARCHAR(21845), replacement VARCHAR(21845), greedy BOOLEAN,
  minMatchLen INT, maxMatchLen INT, minSubMatchLen INT, maxSubMatchLen INT,
  OUT result VARCHAR(21845))
BEGIN
  DECLARE subStr, usePattern, useRepl VARCHAR(21845);
  DECLARE startPos, prevStartPos, startInc, len, lenInc INT;
  SET @@SESSION.max_sp_recursion_depth = 2;
  IF subject REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET result = '';
    -- Sanitize input parameter values
    SET minMatchLen = IF(minMatchLen < 1, 1, minMatchLen);
    SET maxMatchLen = IF(maxMatchLen < 1 OR maxMatchLen > CHAR_LENGTH(subject),
                         CHAR_LENGTH(subject), maxMatchLen);
    -- Set the pattern to use to match an entire string rather than part of a string
    SET usePattern = IF (LEFT(pattern, 1) = '^', pattern, CONCAT('^', pattern));
    SET usePattern = IF (RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$', usePattern, CONCAT(usePattern, '$'));
    -- Set start position to 1 if pattern starts with ^ or doesn't end with $.
    IF LEFT(pattern, 1) = '^' OR RIGHT(pattern, 1) <> '$' THEN
      SET startPos = 1, startInc = 1;
    -- Otherwise (i.e. pattern ends with $ but doesn't start with ^): Set start pos
    -- to the min or max match length from the end (depending on "greedy" flag).
    ELSEIF greedy THEN
      SET startPos = CHAR_LENGTH(subject) - maxMatchLen + 1, startInc = 1;
    ELSE
      SET startPos = CHAR_LENGTH(subject) - minMatchLen + 1, startInc = -1;
    END IF;
    WHILE startPos >= 1 AND startPos <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject)
      AND startPos + minMatchLen - 1 <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject)
      AND !(LEFT(pattern, 1) = '^' AND startPos <> 1)
      AND !(RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$'
            AND startPos + maxMatchLen - 1 < CHAR_LENGTH(subject)) DO
      -- Set start length to maximum if matching greedily or pattern ends with $.
      -- Otherwise set starting length to the minimum match length.
      IF greedy OR RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$' THEN
        SET len = LEAST(CHAR_LENGTH(subject) - startPos + 1, maxMatchLen), lenInc = -1;
      ELSE
        SET len = minMatchLen, lenInc = 1;
      END IF;
      SET prevStartPos = startPos;
      lenLoop: WHILE len >= 1 AND len <= maxMatchLen
                 AND startPos + len - 1 <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject)
                 AND !(RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$' 
                       AND startPos + len - 1 <> CHAR_LENGTH(subject)) DO
        SET subStr = SUBSTRING(subject, startPos, len);
        IF subStr REGEXP usePattern THEN
          IF subpattern IS NULL THEN
            SET useRepl = replacement;
          ELSE
            CALL reg_replace_worker(subStr, subpattern, NULL, replacement, greedy, 
                          minSubMatchLen, maxSubMatchLen, NULL, NULL, useRepl);
          END IF;
          SET result = IF(startInc = 1,
                          CONCAT(result, useRepl), CONCAT(useRepl, result));
          SET startPos = startPos + startInc * len;
          LEAVE lenLoop;
        END IF;
        SET len = len + lenInc;
      END WHILE;
      IF (startPos = prevStartPos) THEN
        SET result = IF(startInc = 1, CONCAT(result, SUBSTRING(subject, startPos, 1)),
                        CONCAT(SUBSTRING(subject, startPos, 1), result));
        SET startPos = startPos + startInc;
      END IF;
    END WHILE;
    IF startInc = 1 AND startPos <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject) THEN
      SET result = CONCAT(result, RIGHT(subject, CHAR_LENGTH(subject) + 1 - startPos));
    ELSEIF startInc = -1 AND startPos >= 1 THEN
      SET result = CONCAT(LEFT(subject, startPos), result);
    END IF;
  ELSE
    SET result = subject;
  END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer with lots of explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
UPDATE tablename 
    SET contentfield = REPLACE(contentfield, '.html', '/') 
    WHERE contentfield like 'www.mydomain.de/%';
```

It should work for the examples in the question.

If you like, you can use the condition to only match rows that actually have ".html" in them.

```
    WHERE contentfield like 'www.mydomain.de/%.html%'
```

Comment: contentfield can contain more links - I added a example to question

Answer (score 1):

I would just export table to CSV or something, then used notepad++/excel/etc. internal tool to replace
'.html' with '/'.

And then import back to SQL.

Also, since mysql supports regular expressions, you can search for your domain, containing .html with it.

```
 mydomain.de[^s]+.html
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

```
 UPDATE tablename 
 SET contentfield = REPLACE(contentfield, '.html', '/') 
 where contentfield  like 'www.mydomain.de%' 
 AND contentfield  like '%html%'
 AND ( contentfield  not like 'www.another-domain.com/somelink%'  OR  
         contentfield  not like 'www.another-domain.com/subfolder/link%' )
```

Comment: contentfield can contain more links - I added a example to question

Comment: unfortunately, i know "www.mydomain.de" as a string, but "another-domain.com" is any link on the web

Comment: Have you some logi for obtain .. "another-domain.com"   ? .. if yes  this logic could be used ..