# Well, I have a problem about recursion in MySql, about creating a recursive factorial function. it gives me error 1424:

Tags: mysql, recursion, mysql-workbench

```
DELIMITER //
create function FactorialR (n int) returns int
begin
    declare resultado int default 1;
    set resultado=FactorialR(n-1)*n;

 return resultado;
 end//
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL functions are not allowed to be recursive.  [Recursive stored functions in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752078/recursive-stored-functions-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You are not to use recursion, but you can always use simple loops

Of course you can use Pocedures which allow recursive calls

> ```
> create function FactorialR (n int) returns int
> begin
>     declare resultado BIGint default 1;
>     DECLARE m int DEFAuLT  1;
>     
> loop_label:  LOOP
>       IF  m = n THEN 
>           LEAVE  loop_label;
>       END  IF;
>             
>       SET  m = m + 1;
>       set resultado=resultado*m;
>   END LOOP;
>  return resultado;
>  end
> ```

> ```
> SELECT FactorialR(4)
> ```
>
> ```
> | FactorialR(4) |
> | ------------: |
> |            24 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1eab4ab52c895040d61e1651b86252fb)*